# MySQL: Get the totals from two columns organised by category

Tags: mysql, sql

Considering the following tables in a MYSQL database:

table1:

```
+------+-----------+----------------------+
| id   |   atual   | category_id  |  user |
+------+-----------+--------------|-------+
| 1    |   100     |  1           |   1   |
| 2    |   150     |  2           |   1   |
| 3    |   50      |  1           |   2   |
+------+-----------+--------------|-------+
```

table2:

```
+------+-----------+----------------------+
| id   |   budget  | category_id  |  user |
+------+-----------+--------------|-------+
| 1    |   100     |  2           |   1   |
| 2    |   150     |  1           |   2   |
| 3    |   50      |  1           |   1   |
+------+-----------+--------------|-------+
```

table3:

```
+------+-----------+
| id   |   name    | 
+------+-----------+
| 1    |   one     |
| 2    |   two     |
| 3    |   three   |
+------+-----------+
```

I want to calculate the totals for 'atual' and 'budget' given in tables 1 and 2 for a given user (1 in my example), organized by category name:

I tried the following query, which is giving me the totals for atual and budget regardless of the categories:

```
SELECT table2.id, table3.name AS name_category, SUM( budget ) , 
(SELECT SUM( atual) FROM table1 WHERE user =1)
FROM table2 INNER JOIN table3
ON table2.category_id=table3.id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a method:

```
select t3.id, t3.name, sum(actual) as actual, sum(budget) as budget
from ((select category_id, sum(actual) as actual, NULL as budget
       from table1
       where user = 1
       group by category_id
      ) union all
      (select category_id, NULL as actual, sum(budget) as budget
       from table2
       where user = 1
       group by category_id
      )
     ) ab join
     table3 t3
     on ab.category_id = t3.id
group by t3.id, t3.name;
```

Comment: The question supposes organizing by categories so I think the inner queries should have GROUP BY category_id and the 'category_id' field in SELECT section.

Comment: This looks strange, but it is (almost) working: It is adding the actual values grouped by category correcty but adding all the budget values in a single category (although there are several categories with budget)

Comment: The budget figure is presented as a total sum where the actual figure is Null

Comment: @NunoNogueira . . . The problem is fixed.  I was still selecting `userId` in the `budget` subquery.

Comment: I'll need a couple of hours to think about how this was done, but it working, thanks!